# what key pressed vscode extensions

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am new to vscode editor and I am creating extensions for this. Is there any event or something which can tell me what key I have pressed. Suppose I am opening vscode editor and then i am pressing `ctrl+A` is there any way to get the value i.e., `ctrl+A`

Comment: Did you check the api reference: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/overview ?

Comment: yes i have read that but i think there is no events to get this value

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you not bind directly to the key shortcut event which could be localized and translated into another letter in different languages.

If you want to execute a command on a keypress, you can use *contributes.keybindings*

These are the relevant links:
[contribution points](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/extension-points) and [key bindings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/customization/keybindings)

Comment: using key bindings we can do any stuff whenever specified key is pressed but  for instance ctrl+v is specified to show 'Hello' in status bar  then whenever i press ctrl+v it shows hello in status bar only and it will not paste any code.

Comment: then you should add the relevant code to your custom function (paste from clipboard in this case - or select all in your original question)